# Converting images of different dimensions into a gif with maximum dimensions

Tags: imagemagick

I have a set of images for an animation, but not all of the dimensions are the same. Some may be 100x100, others might be 99x105, a few with 110x100, and so on.

If I did a simple

```
convert *.png myAni.gif
```

And the first image happened to be a bit smaller in dimension compared to the largest image, the result may be "cut off" because the dimensions of the canvas is not large enough.

How can I either

1. Set the canvas size for the animation, or more preferably,
2. Have imagemagick find the largest width and height of the input set and use that as the canvas size?

The way I am doing it is to supply the first image as my "canvas" image, which would be created with a suitable width/height, and then I do a coalesce and delete 0 like this

```
convert canvas.png 001.png 002.png ... 009.png -coalesce -delete 0 myAnim.gif
```

Answer (score -1):

Unless I'm missing something, I don't see any reason you couldn't use this: http://www.obviousidea.com/windows-software/light-image-resizer/

Comment: Obviously they don’t want to resize the images (and by extension, lose some quality).

Comment: The content of the image is correct: if you manually resized the canvases and did some positioning it would produce the expected animation. There are actually two problems I'm dealing with (canvas size, and frame positioning), so I figured I might tackle the canvas size since it's easier of the two.